# Google Sheet - Copy Rows from Multiple Sheets into a Single Summary Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to maintain separate sheets that aggregate into a single summary sheet in one google spreadsheet while maintaining formatting. I have a code that will copy the contents of the separate sheets into the summary, but the second sheet overwrites the first in the summary sheet. Here's what I have -

```js
function importTable2() {
  // Source 1
  var sourceSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("1");
  var sourceRange1 = sourceSheet1.getDataRange();

  // Source 2
  var sourceSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("2");
  var sourceRange2 = sourceSheet2.getDataRange();  

  // Destination
  var destSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var destSheet = destSS.getSheetByName("Summary");
  var destRange = destSheet.getDataRange();
  destSheet.clear();

  // Copy 1
  var copiedsheet = sourceRange1.getSheet().copyTo(destSS);
  copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange1.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange);
  copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange1.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  destSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
  
    // Copy 2
  var copiedsheet2 = sourceRange2.getSheet().copyTo(destSS);
  copiedsheet2.getRange(sourceRange2.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange);
  copiedsheet2.getRange(sourceRange2.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  destSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet2);

}
```

I think it's because my destination range is the same, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a second destination range (for sheet 2's data) that will be right below the initial destination range (from sheet 1's data) as the data from sheet 1 could have 10 rows today but 20 rows tomorrow.

Any thoughts on how to get source 2 to drop into the destination sheet under source 1 data?

Comment: You can accumulate the each range into an array [][] and give the array to destination sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the value of `destRange` in the "// Copy 2" part of the script:

```
    // Copy 2
  var copiedsheet2 = sourceSheet2.copyTo(destSS);
  destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceRange2.getLastRow(), sourceRange2.getLastColumn());
  copiedsheet2.getRange(sourceRange2.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange);
  copiedsheet2.getRange(sourceRange2.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  destSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet2);
```

Comment: That works to place the source 2 rows below source 1 rows (THANK YOU!), but when I run the function anew, source 1 rows populate into the summary tab twice (three times if I have three source sheets, four if I have four source sheets, etc.) I tried adding a "clear" piece to the function (below), but it still generates the source 1 data for as many sources as I have in the function after the first run. `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary');
    sheet.getRange('A:O').clearContent();`

Comment: Oh! I just included a `destRange` reset for the Copy 1 portion of the script and that did the trick for subsequent generations!! Thank you so much, ADW!